# Get value of select label html via custom attr

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

I want to know how to get with jquery with method val() the selected value of a select tag through a custom attribute inside it.

Example:

```
<select dta-tble="table1" onchange="printTable(event);">
var datatable = $(evt.target).attr("**dta-tble**");

var row = $(**..this the solution..**).val();
```

Thanks.

Comment: Can you pots the sample template with the custom, attribute?

Comment: For future reference:  [jquery selectors](https://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/)

Answer (score 0):

try:

```
var value = $('select[**dta-tble**="table1"]').val();
```

I recomand you don't use ** characters on html attributed, use example data-table="table1" or id="table1" and you can get value more easly

Comment: This work for me. Thanks. And in case of having two selects, how can I do so that the value of one is not overwritten with another?

Answer (score 0):

If you're using jQuery, dont use inline event handlers. You can target elements using the [attribute selector](https://api.jquery.com/has-attribute-selector/)

```js
$("select[dta-tble]").on("change", function(){
    const val = $(this).val();
    console.log(val);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select dta-tble="table1">
  <option>1</options>
  <option>2</options>
  <option>3</options>
</select>
```